# window.location.href does not work, it always returns an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been learning HTML/CSS/JS in my free time. I'm still a noobie and I have encountered this problem while practicing.
I want to create a form where you can type what are you searching for and sumbit button redriects you to google and If it's empty it shows an alert. But the redirect does not work, I always get an alert. 
Can you guide me what Am I doing work ?
Sorry for my english, It isn't my native langue.

```
<form id="myform">
        <input type="search" name="searchedValue">
        <input type="submit" value="Szukaj">
</form>


<script>
    $("document").ready(function() {
        $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
            var searchedValue = $("input[name='searchedValue']").attr("value");
            if (searchedValue) {
                window.location.href = "http://www.google.pl/#hl=plf&output=search&q="+searchedValue;
            } else {
                alert("empty string");
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use [`.val`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `.attr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var searchedValue = $("input[name='searchedValue']").val()
```

you should use `val()`
instead of attr(). Rest of the things are fine.

Comment: This is code from that question, the value doesent matter it is displayed correctly in alert i have added: https://jsfiddle.net/can6uqy0/

So im not uderstand 3 pluses here.

Comment: val() and attr("value") do the same !

Comment: There is a slight difference between these two and in your fiddle, if you will upgrade the jQuery version you will etc the error.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the issue apparently.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myform">
        <input type="search" name="searchedValue">
        <input type="submit" value="Szukaj" onclick="search(event)">
</form>
<script>
    function search(event) {
        // [0] gets the first textbox of current page with name.
        var searchedValue = document.getElementsByName('searchedValue')[0].value;
        if (searchedValue && event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // cancels the event if it is cancelable
            var specs = "height=auto,width=auto";
            var searchUrl = "http://www.google.pl/#hl=plf&output=search&q=" + searchedValue;
            window.open(searchUrl, "_blank", specs);
        } else {
            alert("empty string");
        }
    };
</script>
```

Useful links like [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp). I think it's better to practice with pure javascript and DOM manipulations when you are learning. Anyway, keep up the hard work. :)

Answer (score -1):

Code is fine, i think your browser is blocking your redirect to

```
http://www.google.pl/#hl=plf&output=search&q="+searchedValue;
```

It may happen when you have `https` website and want to redirect to `http`.
Console will silently display error regarding insecure redirect.

Comment: Simply you can change url to https to make it work i think.

Comment: He says that in every scenario the alert pops up instead of running the actual `window.location.href`. The problem here is the `if` statement, not the url.

Comment: This ic code from that question, the value doessent matter it is displayed correctly in alert: https://jsfiddle.net/can6uqy0/
The only problem i can se may be related with thing i have added in this post.